# Convert a string to data frame, including column names

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a string whose structure and length can keep varying, that is

Input:

```
X <- ("A=12&B=15&C=15")
Y <- ("A=12&B=15&C=15&D=32&E=53")
```

What I was looking for this string to convert to data frame

Output Expected:

Dataframe X

```
 A  B  C
 12 15 15
```

and Dataframe Y

```
 A  B  C  D  E
 12 15 15 32 53
```

What I tired was this:

```
X <- as.data.frame(strsplit(X, split="&"))
```

But this didn't work for me, as it created only one column and column name was messed up.

P.S: I cannot hard code the column names because they can vary, and at any given time a string will contain only one row

Comment: `eval(parse(text=paste("data.frame(",gsub("&", ",", X),")")))` I feel bad for suggesting it, but maybe it isn't all that horrible in the current context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to extract the numeric part from the string, and read it with `read.table`.  The pattern `[^0-9]+` indicates one or more characters that are not a number and replace it with a space in the first `gsub`, read that using `read.table`, and specify the column names in the `col.names` argument with the values got by removing all characters that are not an upper case letter (second `gsub`)

```
f1 <- function(str1){
read.table(text=gsub("[^0-9]+", " ", str1), 
         col.names = scan(text=trimws(gsub("[^A-Z]+", " ", str1)), 
             what = "", sep=" ", quiet=TRUE))
 }

f1(X)
#   A  B  C
#1 12 15 15
f1(Y)
#   A  B  C  D  E
#1 12 15 15 32 53
```

Comment: Works beautifully, will wait for two minutes before accepting yours!

Comment: If its not too much to ask, would you mind explaining how your code works, if not for me, others will find it helpful ( one up vote from me for sure )

Comment: @USER3875610 Sure, I was going to update it when my laptop gets so slow.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this too:

```
library(stringr)
res <- str_match_all(X, "([A-Z]+)=([0-9]+)")[[1]]
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.integer(res[,3]), nrow=1))
names(df) <- res[,2]

df
   A  B  C
1 12 15 15
```